# Xamarin: Instantiate Xamarin.Droid or Xamarin.iOS Class

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin and want to write down a generic cross platform code in my Xamarin.Forms app for invoking platform specific implementation which will be there in the Xamarin.Droid or Xamarin.iOS. This platform specific implementation is for using location services of the platform.

For that, I defined an interface called, ILocationTracker in my Xamarin.Forms project, as follows:

```
public interface ILocationTracker
    {
        void Connect();

        void Disconnect();

        void startReceivingLocationUpdates(int priority, int fastestInterval, int interval);

    }
```

I have wrote down a class called **AndroidLocationTracker** in my Xamarin.Droid project folder which implements ILocationTracker interface, and following Android platform specific interfaces:

> 1. IGooglePlayServicesClientConnectionCallbacks,
> 2. IGooglePlayServicesClientOnConnectionFailedListener,
> 3. Android.Gms.Location.ILocationListener

For Android specific implementation, I am referring following link: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/maps_and_location/location/

For instantiation of the class, I am doing following in MyView.xaml.cs which is in the Xamarin.Forms folder:

```
    if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Android) {
                    var type = Type.GetType("MyProjectName.Droid.AndroidLocationTracker");
                    tracker = (ILocationTracker)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
}
```

But, I get runtime error

> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Can somebody help me, how to invoke platform specific class?
Am I missing something? Or Am I on the wrong track?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create platform specific services (in your case `AndroidLocationTracker`) inside the platform specific code. 
Go to your Android project and create the instance for example in your `MainActivity.cs` file. Register your instance in a dependency injection container. Using this technique you have no need anymore to ask for the current platform like you are doing now with `if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Android) {}`

A common container is `Mvx` and comes with MVVMCross (https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Service-Location-and-Inversion-of-Control).

Xamarin.Forms brings its own `DependencyService` (http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/). You find examples for class registration in the documentation. You can create new instances in your shared code via `DependencyService.Get<ILocationTracker>()`.